# Is it possible to cast to a boolean array in php?

Tags: php, ajax, json, casting

I'm sending a PHP script data converted from JSON into serialised form by JQuery (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). PHP interprets the POST data as one big associative array, which is awesome.

What I'm wondering is, is it possible to cast to a boolean array in PHP? And generally, whether you can cast to a typed array in PHP?

At the moment I have an array of booleans in JavaScript which is interpreted as an array of string in PHP. I'm guessing you can't cast in that way, as a PHP array can contain a mix of types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying, you want to convert to something like:

```
array('TRUE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE');
```

to

```
array(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE);
```

?

Then, you could use something like this:

```
$a = array('TRUE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE');

function _str_to_bool($s) {
  return strtolower($s) == 'true';
}

$a2 = array_map('_str_to_bool', $a));

var_export($a2);
// array(true, false, true, true, false)
```

If you want to perform a "real" cast, instead (so, a string will evaluate to false only if == ""), just change the code in the callback function, to do a cast (`(bool)$s` in this case), or whatever you need.

Comment: Also, instead of creating a (short) callback function, you can pass, for example, `create_function('$x', 'return strtolower($x) == "true";')` as the first argument to `array_map()`.

Answer (score 3):

Because post data is all strings your bool values are getting interpreted as strings. In this case you need iterate over the array and cast your values to bools, ex :

```
foreach($values as &$val)
    $val = (bool)$val;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right that PHP is dynamically typed. But you can still coerce/convert the types a little. If you know what the string for `false` and the string for `true`, you can do something like this, to coerce it into an array

```
foreach( $array as &$value ) $value = ($value === $trueStr);
```

(Edit: George or Adil's answers would work equally well, *if* the true/false string values are truthy/falsey values like "1" and "0", but if - for some reason - your array sends you "yes" and "no" instead, then `(bool) $value` will be `true` for both, as both are non-empty strings. This one does a *strict* comparison of the input and the true/false string values - if there's any doubt, a value will be `false`)

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not have a concept of a boolean array like Java does. "array" is a type, just as booleans, integers, and floats are types.

However, an array can *contain* boolean objects. You can use `foreach` to loop through an array and cast individual elements to boolean.

```
foreach ( $_POST as &$post_element ) {
    $post_element = (bool)$post_element;
}
```

Comment: cool - also looping the array using a pointer should work fine, and consuming less memory..

Answer (score 1):

PHP chooses the datatype as needed, you can force something into a specific datatype by specifying it like this:

```
$var = (bool) 1;
```

However why do you need to do the conversation? PHP will change the datatype according to the operation you perform.